# XHR request URL says does not exist when attempting to parse it's content

Tags: python, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest, python-requests

Before I build a full solution to my problem using Scrapy I am posting a simplistic version of what I want to do:

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.whoscored.com/stageplayerstatfeed/?field=1&isAscending=false&orderBy=Rating&playerId=-1&stageId=9155&teamId=32"'

params = {'d': date.strftime('%Y%m'), 'isAggregate': 'false'}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)

fixtures = response.body
#fixtures = literal_eval(response.content)
print fixtures
```

This code is saying that the above URL does not exist. The URL relates to an XHR request that is submitted when you toggle from the 'Overall' to the 'Home' tab of the main table on this page:

```
http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/32/
```

If you activate XHR logging within the Console of Google Developer Tools you can see both the XHR request and the response sent from the server in the form of a dictionary (which is the expected format).

Can anyone tell me why the above code is not returning the data I would expect to see?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have several problems:

- the url should be `http://www.whoscored.com/stageplayerstatfeed`
- wrong `GET` parameters
- missing important required headers
- you need `response.json()`, not `response.body`

The fixed version:

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.whoscored.com/stageplayerstatfeed'
params = {
    'field': '1',
    'isAscending': 'false',
    'orderBy': 'Rating',
    'playerId': '-1',
    'stageId': '9155',
    'teamId': '32'
}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36',
           'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
           'Host': 'www.whoscored.com',
           'Referer': 'http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/32/'}

response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)

fixtures = response.json()
print fixtures
```

Prints:

```
[
    {
        u'AccurateCrosses': 0,
        u'AccurateLongBalls': 10,
        u'AccuratePasses': 89,
        u'AccurateThroughBalls': 0,
        u'AerialLost': 2,
        u'AerialWon': 4,
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

Comment: thanks for that, that worked as i wanted it to. i didnt realise i had to specify the parts of the url after the main address as specific parameters rather than as just part of the url as they are displayed in the console. also, could you explain what the three lines after 'User-Agent' within 'headers' do? thanks...

Comment: @user3045351 sure, those are headers that were sent by the browser when I was inspecting it. You can try to remove them one by one and see if the code breaks - I think at least some of them are not really required. Thanks.