# Extracting a table from a website

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I've tried many times to retrieve the table at this website:
http://www.whoscored.com/Players/845/History/Tomas-Rosicky
(the one under "Historical Participations")

```
import urllib2 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.whoscored.com/Players/845/').read())
```

This is the Python code I am using to retrieve the table html, but I am getting an empty string. Help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired table is formed via an *asynchronous API call* to the `http://www.whoscored.com/StatisticsFeed/1/GetPlayerStatistics` endpoint request to which returns a JSON response. In other words, `urllib2` would return you an initial HTML content of the page without the "dynamic" part. In other words, `urllib2` is not a browser.

You can study the request using *browser developer tools*:

[image]

Now, you need to simulate this request in your code. [`requests` package](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) is something you should consider using.

Here is a similar question about `whoscored.com` I've answered before, there is a sample working code you can use as a starting point:

- [XHR request URL says does not exist when attempting to parse it's content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654659/xhr-request-url-says-does-not-exist-when-attempting-to-parse-its-content)