# GET method with python3 Requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, xmlhttprequest, python-requests

I am trying to get some data from a page. I open Chrome's development tools and successfully find the data I wanted. It's in XHR with GET method (sorry I don't know how to descript it).Then I copy the params, headers, and put all these to requests.get() method. The response I get is totally different to what I saw on the development tools.

Here is my code

```
import requests
queryList={
    "category":"summary",
    "subcategory":"all",
    "statsAccumulationType":"0",
    "isCurrent":"true",
    "playerId":None,
    "teamIds":"825",
    "matchId":"1103063",
    "stageId":None,
    "tournamentOptions":None,
    "sortBy":None,
    "sortAscending":None,
    "age":None,
    "ageComparisonType":None,
    "appearances":None,
    "appearancesComparisonType":None,
    "field":None,
    "nationality":None,
    "positionOptions":None,
    "timeOfTheGameEnd":None,
    "timeOfTheGameStart":None,
    "isMinApp":None,
    "page":None,
    "includeZeroValues":None,
    "numberOfPlayersToPick":None,
    }
header={
    'modei-last-mode':'JL7BrhwmeqKfQpbWy6CpG/eDlC0gPRS2BCvKvImVEts=',
    'Referer':'https://www.whoscored.com/Matches/1103063/LiveStatistics/Spain-La-Liga-2016-2017-Leganes-Real-Madrid',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36',
    "x-requested-with":"XMLHttpRequest",
}
url='https://www.whoscored.com/StatisticsFeed/1/GetMatchCentrePlayerStatistics'
test=requests.get(url=url,params=queryList,headers=header)
print(test.text)
```

I follow this post below but it's already 2 years ago and I believe the structure is changed.

[XHR request URL says does not exist when attempting to parse it's content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654659/xhr-request-url-says-does-not-exist-when-attempting-to-parse-its-content)

Comment: I found that the website will lock my IP and request a human test before unlock my IP. beside that, it come up some script that is still not the data. Please help....I stack here for over 1 month...

Comment: How can this happen...No comment?

Comment: When I just attempted to open that URL in my browser I received a page with the line, 'The page you requested does not exist in WhoScored.com'.

Comment: @BillBell The URL is here: [link](https://www.whoscored.com/Matches/1103063/LiveStatistics/Spain-La-Liga-2016-2017-Leganes-Real-Madrid)

Comment: The Chrome inspector enables you to view the internal representation of a page. This is not necessarily the same as what `requests.get` downloads from a website. When you want to work with what the inspector shows you in Python you need to use a library such as **selenium**. The documentation for it is good and there are quite a few good answers about using it here on SO.

Comment: @BillBell The data I want is from the XHR which return a JSON respond. I will edit my post above to descript it clearly.

Comment: so despair.....

Comment: What data do you want?

Comment: @BillBell thanks for staying with me, actually I figure it out now. You are right, I need to use **selenium**. I don't know the principle behind this, the XHR can not be sent by itself alone. I have to open (or reload) the front end website before getting that JSON. So, tho it's not prefect, but it's solved.

Comment: You're welcome. Best of luck.