# Getting the response content of XHR in Python

Tags: python, json, error-handling, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to get the response content of XHR from the website https://www.whoscored.com. Here is my code

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.whoscored.com/StatisticsFeed/1/GetPlayerStatistics'
params = {
    'category': 'shots',
    'subcategory': 'situation',
    'isCurrent': 'false',
    'playerId': '17',
    'teamId': '',
    'matchId': '',
    'stageId': '',
    'tournamentOptions': '',
    'sortBy': 'seasonId',
    'sortAscending': '',
    'age': '',
    'ageComparisonType': '0',
    'appearances': '',
    'appearancesComparisonType': '0',
    'field': '',
    'nationality': '',
    'positionOptions': '^%^27FW^%^27,^%^27AML^%^27,^%^27AMC^%^27,^%^27AMR^%^27,^%^27ML^%^27,^%^27MC^%^27,^%^27MR^%^27,^%^27DMC^%^27,^%^27DL^%^27,^%^27DC^%^27,^%^27DR^%^27,^%^27GK^%^27,^%^27Sub^%^27',
    'timeOfTheGameEnd': '5',
    'timeOfTheGameStart': '0',
    'isMinApp': '',
    'page': '1',
    'includeZeroValues': 'true',
    'numberOfPlayersToPick': ''
}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Host': 'www.whoscored.com',
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
        'Referer':'https://www.whoscored.com/Players/17/History',
        'Cookie': 'localeEditionShown_en=true; permutive-session=^%^7B^%^22session_id^%^22^%^3A^%^22e5386dfb-c58a-4882-b0e1-2cc2d9518982^%^22^%^2C^%^22last_updated^%^22^%^3A^%^222017-11-22T19^%^3A10^%^3A04.522Z^%^22^%^7D; visid_incap_774904=4xMirl1lRNOgrnN+Sm9S1zNx61kAAAAAREIPAAAAAACAsmaAAbBYMBjQTCqLf/D6wOVO4hdnKjIF; incap_ses_151_774904=/LX+SNRqsR8SzJi7p3YYAjKgGloAAAAApdQygw8VYBxbv/wvl7Be7A==; _gat=1; _gat_subdomainTracker=1; _ga=GA1.2.1522498341.1508602188; _gid=GA1.2.1243543827.1511694421'
        }


res = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)

fix = res.json()

print(fix)
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
>>> exec(open("C:/Users/CEM/Desktop/scrapy.py").read())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    exec(open("C:/Users/CEM/Desktop/scrapy.py").read())
  File "<string>", line 26, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Cem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 892, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Cem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Cem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Cem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem could be?

This question is actually relevant to the following discussion that was posted before:

[XHR request URL says does not exist when attempting to parse it's content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654659/xhr-request-url-says-does-not-exist-when-attempting-to-parse-its-content/47460731#47460731])[1](https://www.whoscored.com)

Comment: Change `.json()` to `.text` and you'll see exactly what it's returning.

Comment: I tried that, too, but that does not give me the response content. I think there might be something wrong with .json(), or somehow the URL does not work.

Comment: @serhatemreAkhanli it seems you need a cookie value in order to make the internal API working. The thing is that in order to get that cookie there are an antibot mecanism in place when you request https://www.whoscored.com/ with some call to https://www.whoscored.com/_Incapsula_Resource including Javascript being evaluated to perform a xhr request before reloading the page with the correct cookies. Also it requires a captcha if it detects that something was wrong with the previous handshake (I guess timing/header etc...)

Comment: @BertrandMartel I added the cookie value as you stated, please see the edited version of the question, but I am not sure whether you meant by this change, and I am getting "invalid syntax" error in the cookie part at this time.

Comment: @BertrandMartel Yes, as you said, the website is designed to prevent web scraping and requires a captcha. I also tried to get the response content by using curl in the command prompt, I got "Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident" error.  Also, when I use the URL link with parameters values in one single URL in the search engine, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't (probably due to the prevention), but I can get the response content from network tab in the inspect element. I wonder if there is a mechanism to access the response content without using captcha or any other preventions.

Comment: @serhatemreAkhanli FYI the anti-scrap techniques used are [this](https://github.com/JonasCz/How-To-Prevent-Scraping/blob/master/README.md#use-and-require-cookies-use-them-to-track-user-and-scraper-actions), [this](https://github.com/JonasCz/How-To-Prevent-Scraping/blob/master/README.md#use-javascript--ajax-to-load-your-content) and [this](https://github.com/JonasCz/How-To-Prevent-Scraping/blob/master/README.md#obfuscate-your-markup-network-requests-from-scripts-and-everything-else).