# Print all incoming XHR requests python

Tags: python

I would like to get all the XHR requests from the URL.

When I inspect the site and go yo Network -> XHR I see multiple XHR links, I would like to get them all once loading has finished. I guess I need a combination of selenium and requests.

I found the following code on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654659/xhr-request-url-says-does-not-exist-when-attempting-to-parse-its-content) but it doesn't give me any output and hands me an error.

I looked for other questions but it doesn't seem like a lot of people had this problem.

Error:

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value
```

My code:

```
####   Gets all XHRs ####
import requests

url= "https://forsikringsguiden.dk/#!/"

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36",
           "X-Requested-With" : "XMLHttpRequest",
           "Host" : "forsikringsguiden.dk",
           "Referer" : "https://forsikringsguiden.dk/"}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

xhr = response.json()
print(xhr)
```

Edit:
Do I need to add any parameters to my code?

Comment: If you insert a `print(response.headers['Content-Type'])` just before your `xhr = response.json()` you'll see that the page returns HTML and not JSON. You can see the HTML using `print(response.text)`.

Comment: I know how to get the HTML. But that's not the issue here.

Comment: That's exactly the issue. You cannot get JSON (`response.json()`) from the HTML response. If you know the server can return a JSON response, then perhaps you need to add an `"Accept: application/json"` header. Or perhaps you need to ask the server admins how to format your request so that it returns a JSON response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to coordinate with the site maintainers. They'll be able to say what headers or parameters you need to send to get a JSON response. Or if they even support JSON at all.

Your original code works given a URL that actually returns JSON:

```
import requests

url= "http://api.plos.org/search?q=title:DNA"

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36",
           "X-Requested-With" : "XMLHttpRequest"}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

xhr = response.json()
print(xhr)
```